# Weblogic Server , Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic

[netbeans screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBXDy.png)

I am using remote weblogic. This is an error when I run the project. What could be the problem?

> Deployment failed. The message was: com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed
>   to load java type corresponding to
>   e=web-app@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <jsp-descriptor>
    <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
    <debug>true</debug>
  </jsp-descriptor>
  <context-root>/WebApplication3</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **weblogic.xml** refers to `web-app_2_5.xsd` but **web.xml** says `web-app version` is 3.1 which is for Servlet specification 3.1

You can see which descriptor suites you:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

or

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5">
</web-app>
```